# Can you select all divs of a class that flow to the next line?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I've got 7 to 12 divs all of the same style which are floated left. I am looking for a css selector for all the ones that flow to a second row. I am pretty sure this is not possible with standard css, but I am wondering if anyone knows any jQuery or other tricks that could get this done. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: What is "flow to a second row"?

Comment: Are there always the same number per row?

Comment: do you know the width of the "outer" div ?

Comment: I want to select the ones in the second row. And I think there will always be the same number in the first row, the second will change, but I don't really want to have to count on there being the same number in the first row.

Comment: yes, i know the width of the outer div.

Comment: You mean select all of the line breaks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you say your self, there is no way to do that with CSS (that I know of). However, it can be done quite easily with jQuery.

One way to do it would be to use a combination of [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) and [offset](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) to only keep the elements with higher top offset than the others (those who doesn't fit on the first row).

```
var $elm = $(".yourSelector"); // Use your selector here
var $secondRowElms = $elm.filter(function () {
   // Compare each item with the first item, to see if it has higher offset
   return ($elm.first().offset().top < $(this).offset().top);        
});
```

**Here is a demo as well:** http://jsfiddle.net/8ppJP/1/

Answer (score 1):

```
var $divs = $('.container .sub');

var arrOffsetTops = [];

$divs.each(function(index,element){
   arrOffsetTops[index]=element.position().top;
   arrOffsetTops[index].newLine = (index==0 ? true : false);
   if(index > 0) {
     if(arrOffsetTops[index] > arrOffsetTops[index-1]) {
        // it's on another line
        arrOffsetTops[index].newLine = true;
     }
  }
});
```

You can then loop through your array, with the index and check for .newLine == true to do whatever you need to do with the div.

**UPDATE:**

An example of how you could use this:

```
var divCount = $divs.length;
for(var i=0; i<divCount; i++) {
 if(true == arrOffsetTops[ i ].newLine) {
  $divs.eq( i ).addClass('newline-marker');
 }
}

.newline-marker {
 -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 10px black;
 -khtml-box-shadow:0 0 10px black;
 -moz-box-shadow:0 0 10px black;
 -o-box-shadow:0 0 10px black;
 -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=2, Direction=0, Color='#000000')";
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=2, Direction=0, Color='#000000');
 box-shadow:0 0 10px black;
 zoom:1;
}
```

Comment: sorry, i am not great with jQuery. but your solution seems great. I have this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/watson/gXttY/). If you could tell me what i am doing wrong that would be great. thanks!

Comment: Funnily enough - firefox 14 latest patch this morning - crashed on that jsfiddle.  I'm not sure what's there (couldn't open it - but caused an immediate crash :)).  Answer above edited for an example of usage.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$('.divs:not(:first)').filter(function(){
   return $(this).position().top - $(this).height() == 0
}).nextAll().andSelf().addClass('next')
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gTzV7/)